# HashMap Implementation Concept

Tags: java, conceptual

I have read it many times, I just wanted to clarify.

HashMap is said as a Array of Arraylists.

Can we say that Array size is the bucket size for a hashmap

Note: I just want to make one correction:

1) No. of buckets is equivalent to Array size
2) Bucket size is the size of the Arraylist.

Sorry of the inconvenience. Please let me know if the above two points are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. In your analogy, each bucket would be one `ArrayList`, so the bucket size would be the size of the `ArrayList`s.  A good implementation would strive to keep all of them roughly the same size, and fairly small.

Answer (score 0):

The number of buckets is the length of the Array.  Each bucket is an ArrayList, and so the bucket size (which may vary from bucket to bucket) would be the length of that ArrayList.  The only reason for that size to be more than one is if the hash code computed for two object added to the HashMap collide (nb, this is probably not the same as the value returned by `hashCode()`, but produced from it in relation to the capacity of/number of buckets in the map).

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is more complicated than that.  For example, a Java `HashMap` is implemented as an array of linked lists.  And in that model, there is no fixed bucket size at all.

If you read the literature, you will discover that there are a number of different ways to organize a hash table, with different characteristics.  The [Wikipedia page on hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) is a good place to start reading.